# Problem Using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with IIS Express & it's annoying the hell out of me.

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I installed IIS Express then installed VS2010 SP1. I get all the IIS Express commands showing up.

However, when I create a new web app, including MVC, the directive at the top get the blue underlining with the error "ASP.NET runtime error: Failed to map the path '/IISExpress/7.5/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT'

If I run VS as administrator, which I'd rather not do, the error is now "ASP.NET runtime error: '/IISExpress/7.5/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT' is not a valid IIS application"

Because of the error, you don't get any intellisense while editing the apsx file, which is annoying. I've tried clicking the "Create Virtual Directory", to no effect. I've tried removing the IIS Express config files so it has to remake them, again to no effect.

Anybody any idea how I can get my IIS Express working with Visual Studio again?

**Update:**
Un-installing SP1 & IIS Express & then re-installing them seems to have made it work. I used copies download from MS to ensure the latest version rather than using Web Platform Installer.
Simon

Comment: I also have this problem and in search for a solution. I have reinstalled the VS 2010 SP1 and also IIS Express but it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: I tried reinstalling them using web platform installer. It just messed things up more. Un-installing them now & have downloaded latest version to try again. We'll see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I'd trust WPI over google to find the latest version of any MS product.  WPI is kept up to date, whereas finding the freshest download link when searching is never easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un-installing SP1 & IIS Express & then re-installing them seems to have made it work. I used copies download from MS to ensure the latest version rather than using Web Platform Installer.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You should run VS always as an administrator.

Your problem looks similar to http://forums.iis.net/p/1177460/1979252.aspx#1979252

Comment: I specifically didn't want to run Visual Studio as administrator as that causes other problems with UAC. IIS Express was designed not to need an local admin account. Looks like I need to try re-applying  SP1.

Comment: VS2010 is specificially designed so that you *don't* have to run it as an administrator for the majority of situations. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/2c215974-221f-4c85-9a14-548d0b76d9fa and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165100.aspx.

Comment: -1 for "You should run VS always as an administrator". See Steve comment.