# IIS 8 Express does not deliver page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, iis-8

When I debug/run my webs with **IIS8 Express**, **IE** starts and then just waits, nothing happens, white page with busy-mouse pointer.

This problem suddenly appeared (**Windows 7** and **Visual Studio 2010**). I decided to reinstall my computer, now with **Windows 8** and ONLY **Visual Studio 2012** and I got the same problem!?

Running **IIS Express** (64 bit) with trace-level it works, and no error are reported, it does however not seem to work if I run the web using 32 bit (and from **Visual Studio**).
I have tested with a **MVC4** project and ASP.NET Forms (Episerver) however the later has some issues running in 64bit (since it has dependencies that need to be 32bit).

My colleagues have the same code and for them **IIS8 Express** works, must be something with my installation?

I have tested reinstalling **IIS8 Express** (and my computer =)) no luck.

**UPDATE**:
I have tried running **IIS 8** (not express) an it works.
For the **MVC** Project it seems to be signalr that "causes" the hang (removing `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs` makes the site work).
I have tried creating a new **MVC** and **ASP.NET** Project and they both work.
So the problem seem to be located around my "old" Projects.
Running mu old projects on my laptop Everything works.

It is starting to drive me crazy

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you click properties on your startup proj, what are the settings? IIS Exp should be picked. From there are you using dedicated port # or dynamic? Are you using a start url or not?

Comment: IISExpress is checked
Project url: http://localhost:12341/
Start action: Current page

Comment: try changing to cassini, **use visual studio development server**. do you get the same hang result?

Comment: Nope, the builtin server work. I do get other problems but thats expected.

Comment: ok, good, we've isolated it to IIS Express. Try again with IIS Express, but **auto-assign port**. does it hang?

Comment: Auto-assign isn't available, I have added some more information above.

Answer (score 2):

Jimmy,

IIS Express has had multiple bug reports with Microsoft. Personally, I'm working in IIS Express now without issue, but there are common complaints about IIS Express hanging after upgrades of VS 2010 SP1 or VS 2012.

That's not exactly your situation, but please read

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/3917b164-2acf-4bec-8a0c-295aeaa5c198/
- [Problem Using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666198/problem-using-iis-express-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1)
- [Visual Studio 2010 iis express freezes when debugging multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836744/visual-studio-2010-iis-express-freezes-when-debugging-multiple-websites)
- [iis express hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114819/iis-express-hangs)

We've determined that you can use Cassini and IIS 8 at the moment. This may be a cop out, but you're right that it's project dependant (I've seen this before), and in your case you may be better off living with and moving on.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up reinstalling Windows8 and this time I formated my disk. After that it works great.  Really odd problem.

Comment: @JimmyEngtröm, that sounds like a beastly effort

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue running my asp.net MVC4 project on localhost under IIS express 8.0. Any time I hit Ctrl F5 to refresh a js file change every js file took 4 to 5 seconds to load. It turns out IIS Exp 8.0 is extremely slow when serving up js files. I ended up uninstalling IIS 8.0 and installing IIS express 7.5 and straight away the problem was fixed. Here are the steps I followed:

- Uninstall IIS express 8.0
- Delete the My Documents\IISExpress folder
- Install IIS express 7.5 ([Link to IIS Express 7.5 download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038))

IIS Express 8.0 seems to be installed with VS 2012 so if you had a new install or possibly a service pack update this might have upgraded your previous IIS express version.

Comment: This works for visual studio 2013 as well.  2013 installs IIS 8.0 express by default.  7.5 works perfect with 2013.